# Making Fashion Websites, Ecommerce Websites, Is islam allow to do that job

Tags: halal-haram, work, internet

I want to know that making fashion websites, or ecommerce websites is allow. or islam does'nt allow this at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assalamualaikum!

You can make Fashion websites, e-Commerce websites, ONLY if nothing in them is against Sharia. like in Fashion websites, you sell clothes of all types, but just dont show exposed body of women. If there is Any haram act in it, then its wrong. just keep halal things in them

Comment: Walikum Salam,

For example, if client give me a design having a women images showing exposed herself. In that case, what i will do ?

Comment: islam does not allow exposed body of women to be seen by anyone, so you are not allowed to follow it in any way